# Customizing UIBarButtonItem with UIAppearance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

I'm trying to customize a `UIBarButtonItem` while it's embedded in a `UINavigationBar`.

I would like to customize the background image as well as the title text attributes.

However, in case the navigation bar is contained in a `UIPopoverController`, I don't want these customizations to take place.

This is my Code:

```
//1. 
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], nil] 
    setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBarBackgroundNormal"] 
    forState:UIControlStateNormal 
    forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

//2. 
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], nil] 
    setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBarBackgroundHighlighted"] 
    forState:UIControlStateHighlighted 
    forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

//3. 
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], nil] 
    setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]} 
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//4. 
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], nil] 
    setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]} 
    forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

//5. 
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], [UIPopoverController class], nil] 
    setBackgroundImage:nil 
    forState:UIControlStateNormal 
    forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

//6. 
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], [UIPopoverController class], nil] 
    setBackgroundImage:nil 
    forState:UIControlStateHighlighted 
    forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

//7. 
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], [UIPopoverController class], nil] 
    setTitleTextAttributes:nil 
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//8. 
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], [UIPopoverController class], nil] 
    setTitleTextAttributes:nil 
    forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

The problem is:
I create a navigation controller as the contentViewController of a popover.
When another view controller is pushed, a back button is automatically created and the appearance which applies is from lines 5,6,7,8 - which is good.

However, when I create a new `UIBarButtonItem` and assign it as the `rightBarButtonItem`, lines 3,4,5,6 are applied instead (meaning, the appearance proxy, for some reason, applied the title attributes from lines 3,4, even though the navigation bar is in a popover. Yet when it comes to the background image, the appearance proxy correctly applied lines 5,6)

When a navigation bar isn't in a popover, everything works just fine (lines 1,2,3,4 are applied).

I can't figure out why the appearance proxy works as it should for the back button, but not for the `UIBarButtonItem` I'm creating, when the navigation controller is in a popover.

Answer (score 0):

I think this paragraph from the docs will help you out:

> In any given view hierarchy, the outermost appearance proxy wins.
>   Specificity (depth of the chain) is the tie-breaker. In other words,
>   the containment statement in appearanceWhenContainedIn: is treated as
>   a partial ordering. Given a concrete ordering (actual subview
>   hierarchy), UIKit selects the partial ordering that is the first
>   unique match when reading the actual hierarchy from the window down.

[UIAppearance Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfcm/UIAppearance/appearanceWhenContainedIn%3a)